# Calculating age in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, ssms, sql-query-store

In the `users` table I have `birth_date` column. I want to select only users under the age 18.

I tried using alias

```
select 
    *, 
    age = case
              when datediff(year, getdate(), birth_date) > 0 
                  then year(getdate()) - year(birth_date) - 1 
                  else year(getdate()) - year(birth_date)
          end 
from 
    users
where 
    age < 18
```

But apparently I cannot use alias in where.

So I tried using case but it's also not gonna work

```
select * 
from users 
where 
    case 
        when datediff(year, getdate(), birth_date) > 0 
            then year(getdate()) - year(birth_date) - 1 < 18
            else year(getdate()) - year(birth_date) < 18
```

What shall I do in this case? I don't want to use a stored procedure.

Comment: Calculating age from a date has been discussed many times. Simple searching will find discussions - including those related to accuracy. But there are multiple ways to address this. Why do you NOT get the current date and subtract 18 years first and then use that value in your filter?

Answer (score 4):

Use `cte`

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *,
      CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(year, getdate(), birth_date) > 0 
          THEN year(getdate()) - year(birth_date) - 1
        ELSE year(getdate()) - year(birth_date) 
      END AS age
  FROM users 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE age < 18
```

demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=398f8785462b8720da1b0e5ece53cf0b)

Answer (score 3):

The *correct* way to do this is not to use `DATEDIFF` at all. It will be less accurate (as it uses date boundaries) and slower (it can't use indexes).

**Instead use `DATEADD` against the current date, do not use functions against the column**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.users
WHERE birth_date > DATEADD(year, -18, GETUTCDATE())  -- maybe cast right-side to DATE?
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d767b337455db9864fb5a5d35ac1334d)

Answer (score 0):

simple use this !

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE DATEDIFF(day,birth_date,GETDATE()) < 6570
```

Comment: I can't because this is not gonna be accurate , I have to check if current date is earlier than birthday of current year to subtract 1 year

Comment: SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE DATEDIFF(day,birth_date,GETDATE()) < 6570   it conver in day like 365*18=6570 belove this all in age 18

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just looking for direction on how to use an alias/CASE statement in a column?

If that's correct, then you'll just need to surround your alias with brackets.

```
select *
      ,case
           when datediff(year, getdate(), birth_date) > 0 
           then year(getdate()) - year(birth_date) - 1 
           else year(getdate()) - year(birth_date)
       end as age
from users
where age < 18
```

Answer (score -2):

Below is one way to calculate age which accounts for leap days and other complexities. This calculates the difference of the yyyymmdd integer values and then divides by 10000 to evaluate only the year difference.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE
    (CAST(FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMMdd') AS int) -
     CAST(FORMAT(birth_date, 'yyyyMMdd') AS int)) / 10000 < 18;
```